# Firestore Node.js fields cannot be accessed

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I wrote a test function to see if I could access the firestore database:

```
exports.testbuy = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    try{
        const docRef = firestore.collection("Stocks").doc("Automobile").collection("BMW").doc("StockRate");
        const snapshot = await docRef.get();
        if (snapshot && typeof snapshot.docs !== 'undefined') {
            snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.data().rates[0]);
            });
        } else {
            console.error('Snapshot is undefined or null');
        }
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err, ', Could not resolve');
}
});
```

Here is my firestore database:

[image: This]

The BMW collection is inside the "Automobile" document, which itself is in the "Stocks" collection. I am trying to access any random index out of the "rates" array (for testing purposes). When I run my code, the output is always

`Snapshot is undefined or null`

How can I change my code so that I get the first value of the rates index?

I tried reading the docs and watching youtube but neither really helped.

Here is the entire code:

```
const express = require("express");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKeys.json");
const app = express();
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://stockrain-3d18d-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app"
});
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const authenticate = async(req, res, next) => {
    const idToken = req.headers.authorization; 
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    req.userId = decodedToken.uid;
    next();
};


exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello from Firebase functions!");

});



exports.testbuy = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  try {
  
    app.use(authenticate)
    const stocks = firestore.collection('Stocks');
    const docRef = stocks
      .doc('Food')
      .collection('McDonalds')
      .doc('StockRates'); 
      
    const doc = await docRef.get();

    if (docRef.exists) {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data().cap);
    } else {
      response.send("Not Found");
    }

  } catch (err) {
    response.status(err).send("Could not Resolve!")
  }
})
```

Thank you :)

Edit: Updated full code

Answer (score 1):

You're loading a single document, not a collection or query. So your `snapshot` variable is a [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#exists), which doesn't have a `docs` property and thus your `snapshot.docs !== 'undefined'` will never succeed.

If you want to test whether the document exists, use `snapshot.exists`. So something like:

```
const doc = await docRef.get();
if (doc.exists) {
  console.log(doc.data().rates[0]);
}
```

Comment: doc.exists() is not a function. doc.exist returns false value

Comment: In the documentation I linked, `doc.exists()` is very much defined as a function. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thats not what I meant. `doc.exists() is not a function` is the error message I am getting

Comment: If you look at the documentation I linked, that'd be unexpected. Agreed? Can you check what type the `doc` is that you get back, e.g. by looking at what properties it has in a debugger?

Comment: Console tells me its a DocumentSnapshot

Comment: Here is the github link for the code (I strongly suspect its either an authorization or connection issue, but idk)

https://github.com/ArjavaTripathi/stockrain

Comment: Aha, on the v8 and older SDKs `exists` was a property: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#exists. Sorry about that. So if that property is `false`, it means the snapshot is for a document that doesn't exist. Authorization and connectivity are not the most likely problems in Cloud Functions, so I'd sooner look for typos in the strings (e.g. extra spaces, non-printable characters, etc)

Comment: Im sure there are no typos anywhere. What im realizing is even using `console.log(await firestore.collection('Stocks').listDocuments());` or `console.log(await firestore.listCollections());` does not log anything on the console

Comment: If there are no documents loaded, are you sure you have stock documents? Note: if the document IDs are shown in italics in the console, there are no actual documents there and the console merely shows these IDs as a placeholder so that it can show subcollections.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the firestore database and of the full code I am using. The document IDs dont show as italics (unless you mean on the terminal? in which case how do I access that?). The github is also updated and linked

Comment: Oof... there's too much going on here. The error message you posted "Snapshot is undefined or null" is caused by what I explain in my answer, and should disappear if you update the code as I've shown there. --- If you still have a problem after that error message is gone, I recommend posting a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).